# Java Vector3d And Vector Logic

Tags: java, vector, 3d, intersection, point

First of all I am having trouble with the concept of a mathematical Vector when being applied to a Vector3d. I understand a vector to be just like a line except it has a direction property.

Now, Vector3d only takes in 3 arguments (x,y,z) in its constructor. I assumed this to be because the vector initially is assumed to start at the origin and go through the designated point. How can we ever have a vector which does not intersect the origin if the only attributes contained in Vector3d are x,y,z?

For example, I am trying to program a function which calculates the distance between two points on a sphere:

```
    //Returns the shortest distance between two points on a sphere
public static double getGreatCircleDistance(Point3d p1, Point3d p2){
    Vector3d v1 = getVector(viewSphereOrigin, p1);
    Vector3d v2 = getVector(viewSphereOrigin, p2);
    v1.normalize();
    v2.normalize();
    return Math.acos(v1.dot(v2)*(viewSphereDiameter/2));
}

//Returns a vector through two given Points in 3d space
public static Vector3d getVector(Point3d start, Point3d terminal){
    return new Vector3d(terminal.x-start.x, terminal.y-start.y, terminal.z-start.z);
}
```

I do not understand however how getVector() can return a vector which passes through the two given points. I researched how to obtain a vector connecting two points:

http://emweb.unl.edu/math/mathweb/vectors/vectors.html#vec6

however fundamentally I still do not understand this. Can someone clear up the logic behind Vector3d for me please and how it can represent an arbitrary vector in 3D space yet it only contains x,y,z?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a small error there: should be `Math.acos(v1.dot(v2))*(viewSphereDiameter/2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector is not a line; it is an entity with a *magnitude* and a *direction*. What it does not have is *location*.

You can represent a vector as the line segment between any two points: the magnitude is the distance between the points, and the direction is given by the direction of the line. Every time the distance and direction of the line are the same you get the same vector.

Since a vector does not have a location, we can arbitrarily choose one of the points to be the origin. This way a triple «x,y,z» uniquely represent a vector with the direction of the line from the point (0,0,0) to the point (x,y,z). But you get the same vector also by picking the points (5,4,2) and (5+x, 4+y, 2+z), or any other two points that are at the same distance and direction from each other.

Comment: Ah thank you! So for this problem we do not need the location since all we need the vectors for is to find the angle. So vectors do work in this case. Is it safe then to definitively say vectors should not be used to calculate points of intersection in 3d space?

Comment: Vectors can be useful for dealing with points. Since a vector is basically a "displacement" you can add a vector to a point to obtain another point. You can't add two points in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Vector3D means a [x,y,z] starting from the origin. If you would like to store a vector in 3D space (called Ray) you should store two Vector3D:
1. the starting point and the end point of the vector
**OR**
2. the origin and the direction of the vector.